# false 'error: package * does not exist' in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kapt

I've got a bunch of errors in AS which basically tell me that there is no file and / or it wasn't able to read it. The problem is, all the files it's looking for are there. This must be and AS related issue. Some examples:

**Error 1:**

```
error: package com.blazecode.scrapguidev2.ui.Items.enums does not exist
import com.blazecode.scrapguidev2.ui.Items.enums.Modpack;
                                                ^
```

[image: it's right there]

As you can see the file is right there.

**Error 2:**

```
error: package com.blazecode.scrapguidev2.ui.Items.util does not exist
import com.blazecode.scrapguidev2.ui.Items.util.ModpackTypeConverter;
                                               ^
```

[image: same story here]

Same story here

Things I've tried:

- Clean build
- Rebuild project
- Invalidate cache and restart (ticked both boxes)
- Delete .idea
- Delete build
- Delete app/build
- Restart computer

Versions:

- Kotlin: 1.7.10
- Gradle: 7.3.1
- AndroidStudio: Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335

How could this be fixed?

Comment: It looks like your package is `items`, but your package import is using `Items` - note the capital letter. Why are those different?

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the issue. It's really odd, because it has been working that way for 2,5 years